# Adding contextual/private variable in an ES6 class (without referencing this.)

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I have a framework that allows classes to be defined in a modular nature - part of this includes predefined variables such as `v`.
I am looking for a way to, from within the class, be able to reference `v.test` rather than `this.v.test`

I have tried a Proxy but I cannot determine the component it comes from.
I have also tried binding a new context (but `this` is still required)

The current class:

```
class test extends BaseClass {
    constructor(){
        this.v = {data: 'test'}
    }

    getData(){
        console.log(v.data) // goal is to equal 'test'
    }
}
```

Example using functions:

```
function test(){
    this.v = {data: 'test'}
    const v = this.v;
    this.getData = function(){
        console.log(v.data) // this does equal 'test'
    }
}
```

Currently, v is not defined in the original context.
I am looking to be able to reference this.v from any instance of the class without having to call `this.v`

The data should not be shared per instance.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of this exercise is aside from making code more ambiguous than it needs to be. Regardless, you're going to have to use `this` at least once in any method that wishes to access anything from the `this` context.

Comment: I fail to see how it makes the code ambiguous. From the point of view of anybody adding code to the system, there should be nothing extra. There would, in fact, be less code. The ideology is that `v` references the data store for the current component context. As mentioned - I am aware of how to do it if I construct pseudo classes but would much rather keep ES6 classes.

Comment: Wrap the method in `with (this)`?

Answer (score 0):

This is simply not possible, because in ECMA classes, declaring variables is not possible, you can declare fields but theses will only be accessible from `this`.